# How to POST multiple large image files via Volley Android

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-volley, retrofit

I am trying to post around **10 images** via **volley** by converting it to **base64** but Volley post the images multiple time due to its retry policy. I am already compressing the files and i also tried changing  its timeout but problem still exist. **Retrofit** also doing same.

Comment: whats the  error you are getting?

Comment: I am not getting error. Volley post the single image multiple time, thats the problem

Comment: give diifferent parameter for different image.

Comment: like,,, params.put("pic", temp);

Comment: have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need/use base64?

Are you using get rather than post?

Use multipart file upload for large files, for instance (with retrofit):

```
public interface FileUploadService {

    @Multipart
    @POST("/upload")
    void upload(@Part("myfile") TypedFile file,
                @Part("description") String description,
                Callback<String> cb);
}
```

Comment: I need to use base64 because server accepts this way

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Android Asynchronous Http Client** for multipart request. 
Refer this [link](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)

HttpClient support **Base64.**

Comment: I was going to recommend the same, this library do a good job in terms of networking, much better than volley. I remember using it too to upload images, they were big, and this library worked as a charm. Give it a try.